# Default disk partitions

Tags: installation, partitioning

When I installed Ubuntu 12.10, I installed it onto a 500 GB hard drive using the default partitioning.

Looking at the hard drive in Disks
[image]

I see the main partition (`/dev/sda1` = 496 GB) and the swap partition (`/dev/sda5` = 4.3 GB). I also see another partition (`/dev/sda2` = 4.3 GB), which is not mounted. Its type is `Extended` and its contents are `Extended Partition`.

Here is the output from `ls /dev/sda*`:

```
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5
```

**Why aren't there partitions 3 & 4? And what is `/dev/sda2` for?**

Comment: Totally unrelated... but I hope you're not using that drive anymore. It's failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partitions in the traditional partitioning scheme (MSDOS table, not GPT) is working with *primary* and *extended* partitions. One can have four primary partitions at maximum, or three primary and an extended in which the extended partition can hold a few more (inside it).

The kernel represents all primary partitions as 1-4 and all extended from 5 and up. The `sda2` you're seeing is the extended "umbrella" partition, which holds just one more partition: `sda5`. This numbering scheme is just the way it's being represented.

In your case with just two actual partitions it wouldn't have been necessary to create an extended partition - as you're not hitting the amount of primary partitions limit.

#### Further readings

- [Wikipedia: PC Disk Partitioning types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#PC_partition_types)
- [Why am I unable to do anything with my extended partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/243376/88802)